# How to get user's timezone information in bixby?

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I am developing location based app for bixby, where i do need user's location information like latitude, longitude and timezone. However, I am able to get latitude and longitude but unable to get timezone. Please let me know what node should i use to get that information?

Answer (score 0):

Its in the variable $vivContext. More details here: https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/actions.js-actions#passing-user-context-information